# Registrering a bot fails asking a code parameter

Tags: bots, botframework

I registeres a bot on:

https://dev.botframework.com

There is a test function. Whn I click on the button i get this message:

```
BadRequest
{
  "Message": "The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter."
}
```

What does it mean? I have registered several bot but never had this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I deleted the web apps and redeployed
now everything is OK

I don't know why

Comment: If this the final answer then please mark question as "answered" to help others find it quickly